# Could not locate aapt. Please ensure you have the Android buildtools installed

Tags: android, flutter

```
Could not locate aapt. Please ensure you have the Android buildtools installed.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_arm64.
Is your project missing an android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

In debug console of vscode showing this error during running of project.

Comment: Do you have  Android buildtools installed? If not Android SDK Manager can do that for you.

Comment: Issue happen due to android sdk located at my unmount drive, which will need manual mount step to ubuntu in each system boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure android sdk installed or not. If installed and configured, check android SDK is stored on un-mount drive, if this is the case, try to mount the drive. I disabled auto mount feature of my hard-disk partition in my ubuntu os that's create the problem.